# Sum a list by values

Tags: python, list, sum

I am trying to sum a list by values in python and I am not having any luck. What I would like to end up with is three summed values.

```
lst = [100, -1, -2, -3, 100, -1, -2, -3, 100]

100 -1-2-3 = 94

100 -1-2-3 = 94

100 = 100
```

Comment: You want sum of distinct values in lst? `sum(set(lst))`

Comment: What is it that makes it `100 -1 -2 -3` instead of `100 -1 -2 -3 +100` ? Is the split triggered every three things, or by every 100 or by every positive number or by something else?

Comment: No Actually what i am looking for is for it to loop through the list and sum until it hits another positive number then save that sum and reset the counter and continue

Comment: Every positive number TessellatingHeckler

Comment: I have tried using a While loop and suming the values. and i have tries if for loops and if statements. in both cases the seem to step out before as soon as the first condition is met. I cannot seem to get it to go past the for value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this?

```
s = []
for i in lst:
    if i > 0 or len(s) == 0:        
        s.append(i)     # start a new element in s when element is larger than zero
    else:
        s[-1] += i      # otherwise add it to the last element of s

s
# [94, 94, 100]
```

Or if you use pandas:

```
import pandas as pd:
ser = pd.Series(lst)
ser.groupby((ser > 0).cumsum()).sum()

#1     94
#2     94
#3    100
#dtype: int64
```